# while loop keeps executing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand why the while keeps executing even though I have written the name "gabriel" or the name "tommy"

```
nombre = ""
while nombre != "gabriel" or nombre !="tommy":
nombre = input()
if nombre != "gabriel" or nombre != "tommy":
    print("ingrese su nombre nuevamente")
else:
    print("su nombre es ")
    break
```

Comment: not `gabriel` or not `tommy` means anything other than those two words will trigger the while loop. In your case, in the first line, the empty string `nombre=""` means it's neither gabriel nor tommy. So the while loop is getting executed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `or` where you should be using `and`.  However, you are also making two checks where you only need one, and initializing `nombre` unnecessarily. Consider this instead:

```
while True:
    nombre = input()
    if nombre != "gabriel" and nombre != "tommy":
        print("ingress su nombre nuevamente")
    else:
        print("su nombre es", nombre)
        break
```

or using `or` correctly:

```
while True:
    nombre = input()
    if nombre == "gabriel" or nombre == "tommy":
        print("su nombre es", nombre)
        break

    print("ingress su nombre nuevamente")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nombre != "gabriel" or nombre !="tommy"
```

No matter what the user enters, this condition will always be true.

If they enter "gabriel", then it is not equal to "tommy".

If they enter "tommy", then it is not equal to "gabriel".

Use `and` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 0):

Below statement always return true and the loop won't stop. I guess u want to use "and" instead or in below statement.

nombre != "gabriel" or nombre != "tommy"